# My HR department just called all my references - 60 days after my start date. Should I be concerned?

Tags: references

As the title suggests, one of my references reached out to me today and told me he got a call from my HR department. I think it is strange that they are just now calling my references, since I've been in the role for 60 days. This seems unusual, should I be concerned?

Comment: How have you been doing at your job? Have you missed days/deadlines/projects/etc.? Have there been regular check-ins with management, HR, and feedback? Have you received any performance notes, negative feedback, or otherwise exhibited problematic behavior (missing meetings, causing incidents, lost accounts, etc.)? It's not uncommon if the HR department needs to be on their best behavior and do their due diligence.

Comment: Did not down vote, just saying.

Comment: Hi David! As far as I know, no. I've been getting good feedback during my 1:1 with my new manager. They even mentioned a potential promotion if I continue working at this pace.

Edit: I've been at this job for 60 days. I have not missed any meetings/projects/negative feedback.

Comment: I agree with Joe. It's probably just HR catching up.

Comment: Are you nearing the end of a probation period?

Comment: Could be in light of the promotion.

Answer (score 5):

I'd ask your manager or HR about it.

It *could* be a red flag but it could also be that they're just trying to get all their ducks in row in-so-far as paperwork is concerned. Like maybe it's a procedure that the hiring manager doesn't put a lot of stock in and he didn't realize it was an absolute requirement that the company has.

But it could also be that something has happened that makes them doubt some of your credentials. You'd have more insight into that than we would however.

Comment: Thank you. All my credentials and prior experience are true and verifiable. I'm hoping it is just a dot the i's and cross the t's and my anxiety getting the best of me.

Comment: "anxiety" -- that's HR's job ... cause employees stress. YMMV.

Comment: It is most likely backlog. You are already working for them for 60 days, so if they want to fire you, they would've just done that without bothering calling the references. Why would they even bother at that point? If anything, they want to keep you and realized they have incomplete paperwork, so they go and finish it.

Answer (score 0):

It's called: *"due diligence."*  Covering the company's backside.  Don't worry about it.

Companies have actually learned – the *very* hard way, unfortunately – that "not everyone is what they seem to be."  Of course **you** are not, but "that's why they do it.  Sometimes."